# Showing a dialog box instead of a partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following Partial view , which i am rendering on ym manin view:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.SwitchJoin
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeDevicesSwitch", "Switch", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "result",
    LoadingElementId = "progress2",
    HttpMethod= "POST"
    ,
    OnSuccess = "createsuccess",
    OnFailure = "createfail"




}))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Switch.SwitchID)
    <div>
<span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GeneralSwitchTo)</span>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.GeneralSwitchTo, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.GeneralSwitchTo) <span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.ShowSwitchNames) </span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(a=>a.ShowSwitchNames, "Tag", new { @id = "ChoiceTag2" })<span>Tag</span> 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(a=>a.ShowSwitchNames, "Name", new { @id = "ChoiceName2" }) <span>Name</span>  
    <input type="submit" value="Assign To Switch" class="btn btn-primary"/>    
    </div>

}
<p><img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress2" /></p>
<div id ="result"></div>
```

This partial view only contains a dropdown list and two radio buttons. but is there a way to show a dialog that contains this partial view? so if a user clicks on a link for example "Show More Options", to populate a dialog containing this partial view ?

second question , i need the scripts which are referenced on the main view to work on the populated dialog also

**Edit**
I have the following function inside my Razor view, the main idea is to fire a function that shows the returned html inside a dialog:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loadview")(function() {
            //Make it a dialog box. Note that you don't have to do this every time the button is called, so you might want to make it dialog on document ready or something.

            $("#showoptions").dialog({
                title: "My Dialog",
                width: 400,
                height: 200
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Switch/ShowOptions")',
                type: 'get',
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#dialogBox').html(html);
                    $("#dialogBox").dialog("show"); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.
                }
            });
        })
```

and the button which should fire the script is :-

```
<input type="button"  value="Assign Devices To Another Switch" id="loadview" /> 
<div id="showoptions"></div>
```

but currently when i click on the link no dialog will be displayed and i also get the following error on chrome console :-

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 1484:602 (anonymous
>   function) 1484:602 fire jquery-1.8.2.js:974 self.fireWith
>   jquery-1.8.2.js:1082 jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.8.2.js:406
>   DOMContentLoaded jquery-1.8.2.js:83 event.returnValue is deprecated.
>   Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

can anyone advice what might be the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: $("#loadview")(function() isn't the correct syntax. If you want to add a click handler to a button using jquery, follow this http://api.jquery.com/click/ . You can also simply add onclick="SomeMethod()" to your button html, where SomeMethod is a function that calls your ajax request. You could put $("#showoptions").dialog in the document.ready function so that it creates a dialog when the page is loaded.

Comment: Also make sure you have an error handler in your ajax call. That way you can see if there is a problem connection to the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jquery UI Dialog Box Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

What you need to do is use the jquery ui dialog box. Essentially all you have to do is load the contents of your partial view in to a div and make the div a dialog box. Then you can open and close the dialog box. Assuming that the view you have shown is the partial that you want to display, you would need to put something like the following html in the main view:

```
 <input type="button" onclick="LoadPartialView()" value="Open Dialog" />  
 <div id="dialogBox"></div>
```

Here I have added an onclick event handler and created a div called dialogBox. That box will become the dialog box.

```
function LoadPartialView(){
   //Make it a dialog box. Note that you don't have to do this every time the button is called, so you might want to make it dialog on document ready or something.

   $("#dialogBox").dialog({
    title: "My Dialog",
    width: 400,
    height: 200
    });

    $.ajax({
    url: 'SomeActionName',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(html){
        $('#dialogBox').html(html);
        $("#dialogBox").dialog("show"); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.
   } 
});
```

});

Now you will also need to use $("#dialogBox").dialog("close") in order to close the box.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but what is .divContent exactly ?

Comment: That's a typo and/or crappy copy and paste. It should be dialogBox

Answer (score 1):

to dynamically load a partial view you need to use an ajax call

```
$('.btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: { id: "ID" },
        success: function(result){
            $('.divContent').html(result);
            //load your dialog
        } 
    });
});
```

on your controller

```
public PartialViewResult Action(int id){
    var model = //populate your model
    return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
}
```

for click events on the partial you need to tie the event to the document

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSubmit', function(){
    //your script here
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but will this display the partial view inside the main view , or it will display it inside a dialog ?

Comment: as i know how to render the partial view inside the main view, but what i need is to render the partial view inside populated dialog box ?

Comment: this will put the partial view into a div on the main view.  Put a display none on that div and popup the div into a dialog using jquery dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: im surprised you aren't specifying the event to trigger the function on.  Try changing your $(#...)(function to a click event like in my code above to see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

The below code will render your partial view in a jquery ui dialog when you click "Show More Options" link on the main page.

Your HTML would look something like in the main view

```
<div id="wodialog"></div>
@Html.ActionLink("Show More Options", "MoreDetails", "SummaryReport",
                    new { param = "Some value" },
                    new { @class = "wodetail" })
```

and your script in the main view

```
$(function () {
    $('#wodialog').dialog({
        title: "More Options",
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        resizable: true,
        modal: false
    });

    $('.wodetail').click(function () {
        $('#wodialog').load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and the controller action should return the partial view

```
public ActionResult MoreDetails(string param)
{
     return PartialView("_ChangeDevicesSwitchPartial", model);
}
```